# Como obter uma lista com os processos em execução do windows em python?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, processo

Gostaria de saber como obter os processos em execução do windows e armazená-los em uma lista em python.

```
from os import system
system('tasklist')
```

Sei que o código acima mostra os processos, mas gostaria de ter como botá-los em uma lista, mesmo que seja utilizada outra biblioteca.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para uma solução *cross-platform*, utilize o pacote [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil).

1 - Instale-o do github ou (mais fácil) com o pip:

```
pip install psutil
```

2 - Execute o seguinte programa de exemplo:

```
import psutil as ps

print('Lista de processos em execução:')
for proc in ps.process_iter():
    info = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name'])
    print('Processo: {} (PID: {})'.format(info['pid'], info['name']))
```

Ele lista os dados (nome e pid) dos processos um a um, obtidos através de um dicionário. Mas se quiser construir uma lista só com os nomes, por exemplo, é só fazer:

```
processos = [proc.name() for proc in ps.process_iter()]
```

A lista com os métodos de acesso a informação do processo que você pode usar (na variável `proc`, ilustrada no código acima) está [na documentação da classe `Process`](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process).

Answer (score 2):

Descobri [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632234/list-running-processes-on-64-bit-windows) uma possível solução:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()

for process in c.Win32_Process():
    print(process.ProcessId, process.Name)
```

[Referência](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html)

Não testei porque não tenho windows, mas se não resultar eu retiro a resposta sem problema

Comment: À risca, só a primeira funcionou, @miguel.

Comment: @Benedito ainda bem que ajudou. Experimentaste todas certo? Vou eliminar as outras, porque como não testei vou tirar para não ter alternativas erradas